# If I dual boot Ubuntu on my Windows desktop and then I use Ubuntu, is that considered native ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ros

Essentially I would like to Learn ROS with Gazebo and Rviz. So if I have to get rid of windows to use those efficiently I would. If I dual boot would those programs run just as well as if I had only Ubuntu on my system?

Comment: Yes, a dual-boot means two different OSes actually installed in the same hardware and running independently. There's no difference between that and a standalone Ubuntu (or Windows).

Comment: Awesome thank you for letting me know!